# Access javascript's data on finished event's function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a jQuery plugin, which have an event named `completeCallback`.

In the next code I'm calling a following function:

```
// code before...
    ui.completeCallback = function(success, data, errorCode) {
        if (success) {              
            console.log(this);
        }
    };
// code after...
```

which outputs this into the console, and I want to access the highlighted line:

[image]

How can I do that on `<function scope>` > `Closure` ? 
I know how to access something like `this.id` which returns me `cbigtzl`.

Thanks for help

**==== UPDATED ====**

[Here is a website demonstrating this plugin named DamnUploader for jQuery](http://safron.su/playground/damnUploader/demo-bootstrap/)
And the source code for the .js is here - almost the same as mine: http://safron.su/playground/damnUploader/demo-bootstrap/js/uploader-setup.js
. Search for the `ui.completeCallback` section

**==== UPDATE 2 ====**
Here is a console.log output: 
[image]

Comment: We need more information. What plugin? Probably it has a function to get the name of the file.

Comment: @dystroy - No it's not working, already tried it. 
newboyhun - I updated the question, pls check it out

Comment: Are you using angular? 
$scope.Closure?

Comment: My guess is that `filenameNew` is the name of a variable over which the function closes. The console shows it to you for debugging purposes, but one of the principles of lexical closures is to make such variables private.

Comment: @ValentinWaeselynck - means it's not accessible, right ?

Comment: @JoakimM - no, I'm using a jQuery, without other frameworks/libraries

Comment: @aspirinemaga I'm afraid so, not from the function at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrolling down in the [plugin's github](https://github.com/safronizator/damnUploader/) shows this example. I'm assuming your `// code before...` is the `.on('du.add'` which means it should be accessed via `this.file.name`.

```
$fileInput.on('du.add', function(e) {
    console.log('File added: ' + e.uploadItem.file.name);
    e.uploadItem.completeCallback = function(succ, data, status) {
        console.log(this.file.name + " was uploaded. Recieved data: ", data)
    };
});
```

Also within the source of the second link you can see the variable `filename` populated in the section with the `ui.completeCallback`.

```
var filename = ui.file.name || ""; // Filename property may be absent when adding custom data

// We can call preventDefault() method of event to cancel adding
if (!isTextFile(ui.file) && !isImgFile(ui.file)) {
    log(filename + ": is not image. Only images & plain text files accepted!");
    e.preventDefault();
    return ;
}

// We can replace original filename if needed
if (!filename.length) {
    ui.replaceName = "custom-data";
} else if (filename.length > 14) {
    ui.replaceName = filename.substr(0, 10) + "_" + filename.substr(filename.lastIndexOf('.'));
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not be able to understand your answer properly, but I ask anyway - does it mean it can't be accessed ? thanks

Comment: @aspirinemaga are you sending back `filenameNew` on the server's end? if so can you update the question with the server's response?

Comment: @aspirinemaga if this is the case, can you just `console.log(data)` as that should be the responseText from the server.